# Can anyone identify these moths?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

Here are two lepidopterans I collected in Oregon (USA). The wingspan of the bigger one (on the left) is ~4 cm. I spent a lot of time browsing this [website](http://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/gallery) hoping to find a match, but I didn't have success.

[image: 2 Oregon moths]

Comment: Out of interest, did you find these in the same place at the same time? They have fairly different phenologies...

Comment: @theforestecologist approximately at the same place and time. Time period 1 month, place - the same region of a town.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one on the left is a **Lunate Zale Moth (*Zale lunata*)**.
See Western Washington University's [PNW moths page](http://pnwmoths.biol.wwu.edu/browse/family-erebidae/subfamily-erebinae/tribe-omopterini/zale/zale-lunata/) for more detailed info.

[image: http://pnwmoths.biol.wwu.edu/browse/family-erebidae/subfamily-erebinae/tribe-omopterini/zale/zale-lunata/]

The one on the right is a **Forage Looper Moth (*Caenurgina erechtea*)**.
See [here](http://bugguide.net/node/view/412879) for an image similar to the one in the question.
And again take a look at Western Washington University's [PNW moths page](http://pnwmoths.biol.wwu.edu/browse/family-erebidae/subfamily-erebinae/tribe-euclidiini/caenurgina/caenurgina-erechtea/) for more detailed info.

[image]